# Appending two casted class lists together

Tags: c#, list, casting

I have a `Cat` class and a `Dog` class that implement an interface called `IAnimal`.

I have a method that fetches a list of `cats` and `dogs`. 
Currently I can cast the `cats` to an `IAnimal` and add it to the `animalList`.

```
List<IAnimal> animalList;

...

public void setUpList(List<Cat> cats, List<Dog> dogs){
   animalList = cats.ToList<IAnimal>();
}
```

Is there an eloquent way to cast both the `cats` and `dogs` to an `IAnimal` and combine them to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) and `ToList()` simply. like this:

```
List<IAnimal> animalList = cats.Union(dogs.Cast<IAnimal>()).ToList();
```

Just don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` to your `using` directives.

Comment: I get the error message that I'm unable to cast type <UnionIterator> to a type GenericList

Comment: @lost9123193 - it should be `cats.Union(dogs.Cast<IAnimal>()).ToList()`;

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use [Enumerable.Cast<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method and union them:

```
cats.Cast<IAnimal>().Union(dogs.Cast<IAnimal>());
```

Comment: if I had more than 2 objects would I just append another Union?

Comment: @lost9123193 - yes, you can Union any number of `IEnumerable<>`s since any Union gets you another `IEnumerable<>` (it's "fluent").

Comment: Ah I see I get an error that says I cannot implicitly convert an IEnumerable to a generic list